How to combine 2 source result in one table in Apache Seatunnel
I am using hazelcast json and calling seatunnel.
Here are the multiple sources
    "source": [
    {
        "plugin_name": "S3File",
        "bucket": "s3a://bucket-name",
        "path": "/path/to/excel/file.xlsx",
        "fs.s3a.endpoint": "s3.region.amazonaws.com",
        "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider": "com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider",
        "file_format_type": "EXCEL",
        "skip_header_row_number": 1,
        "result_table_name": "user_data_from_excel",
        "sheet": 0,
        "schema": {
            "fields": {
                "user_id": "string",
                "user_name": "string",
                "email": "string",
                "role": "string",
                "status": "string"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "plugin_name": "Http",
        "url": "http://api-endpoint.com/api/users/graphql",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "{\"query\":\"query GetAllUsers($filter: UserFilter) { getAllUsers(filter: $filter) { userId userName email role status createdDate lastLoginDate } }\",\"variables\":{\"filter\":{\"status\":\"ACTIVE\"}}}",
        "format": "json",
        "poll_interval": 3600,
        "result_table_name": "user_data_from_api",
        "json_field": {
            "userId": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].userId",
            "userName": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].userName",
            "email": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].email",
            "role": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].role",
            "status": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].status",
            "createdDate": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].createdDate",
            "lastLoginDate": "$.data.getAllUsers[*].lastLoginDate"
        },
        "schema": {
            "fields": {
                "userId": "string",
                "userName": "string",
                "email": "string",
                "role": "string",
                "status": "string",
                "createdDate": "string",
                "lastLoginDate": "string"
            }
        }
    }]

I want to combine the source table 1 user_data_from_excel and source table 2 user_data_from_api into one and wants to store in database through seatunnel.
I did store in multiple tables. but that is not useful for me.
Similar seatunnel example is as below
source [
    hive {
      pre_sql = "select .... from A'" 
      parallelism = 6 
      table_name = "A"
      metastore_uri = "xxxxx"
      result_table_name = "result_table_A"
    }
    hive {
      pre_sql = "select .... from B" 
      parallelism = 6 
      table_name = "B"
      metastore_uri = "xxxxx"
      result_table_name = "result_table_B"
    }],transform {},sink {
    clickhouse {
        host = "1xxxx" 
        database = "xx"
        table = "sink_table"
        fields = [....]
        username = "default"
        password = "default"
        bulk_size = 4000000
        clickhouse.socket_timeout = 300000
        clickhouse.connection_timeout = 300000
        clickhouse.dataTransferTimeout = 300000
        retry = 3
    }

How to combine 2 sources in seatunnel?
